# How can I replace the hyphens in front of child terms with something else?

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

What code is responsible for adding `-` in front of taxonomy term sublevels on a taxonomy field in a node edit form?

[image: screenshot]

Even though the most non-intrusive way to override it is preferred, I'm comfortable even with core patches.

Comment: @leymannx thank you for trying to improve the question but I'm not trying to _remove_ them, I wanted to change the style. For now I've set it to `'└&nbsp;'` for example

Comment: Ah yeah, good! Clarification always is an exchange. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no easy way to override them, they are added by `TermSelection::getReferenceableEntities` in `core/modules/taxonomy/src/Plugin/EntityReferenceSelection/TermSelection.php:73`:

```php
$options[$vocabulary->id()][$term->id()] = str_repeat('-', $term->depth) . Html::escape($this->entityRepository->getTranslationFromContext($term)->label());
```

If you decide to edit it, I suggest using a Composer patch system afterwards if you are using Composer.